# plots in r markdown don't appear if they are the same

Tags: r-markdown

I was trying to generate an r markdown html/pdf docuement and everything worked apart from the code and images didn't appear. What I discovered is that images don't appear if you have two that are the same. In the example below you only get 2 plots, event though 4 are asked for. If you give them all different titles (main='xx') then they all appear.

Is this a known issue that could be causing my problems? Any advice appreciated.

````
```{r pressure, echo=TRUE}
cat('HELLO')
plot(pressure) # only one of these plots bu it seems to be random
cat('HELLO1')
plot(pressure) #
cat('HELLO2')
plot(pressure) #
cat('HELLO3')
plot(pressure) 
plot(pressure,main='plot3') #this one plots
````

Comment: Good question. You might just have to have each plot in it's own R chunk